# Opencv is not working in Qt5.13. App is always crashing in windows

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have installed Qt5.13 and linked opencv version 4.0 . But application is crashing when I am trying to use opencv library; otherwise it will work

.pro file

```
 INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\build\include
 LIBS += -L"C:\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc15\\lib" \
         -lopencv_world410
```

Mainwindow.cpp

```
   #include "mainwindow.h"
   #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
   #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

   MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
              : QMainWindow(parent)
              , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
   {
        ui->setupUi(this);

        cv::Mat img = cv::imread("qq.jpg");
        cv::imshow("ee",img);
        cv::waitKey(0);
   }

   MainWindow::~MainWindow()
   {
       delete ui;
   }
```

Every solution is appreciated.

Comment: Do you get a Windows error code? Maybe, it just fails to locate the opencv DLL at application start. (Setting the PATH in environment or just copying related DLLs into the folder of exe might fix it.)

Comment: Are you trying to link with OpenCV statically or dynamically? Static linking rather failes when building, not at the startup. In Windows world if you use the latter approach (you still need a linkage lib, yes), then @Scheff is right, you forgot to put dlls into your build dir (or wherever it is supposed to be found by your executable).
Also you couls have gotten OpenCV built with some dependency (MSVC Redistributable? Specific 3-rd party library?) which is not present.

Comment: opencv path was missing in "path" environment variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opencv path was missing in "path" environment variable

Answer (score 1):

This is how I included my OpenCV DLL in my .pro file. Yes, DLL, I prefer just using the functions I need instead of including the whole OpenCV Library in my project.

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/Libs/OpenCV \
-lopencv_core320 \
-lopencv_imgproc320 \
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be with the project configuration. You can try the following configuration and run again:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\build\include
LIBS += -LC:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib \
    lopencv_world410.lib
```

**So what changed?**

- Original: `"C:\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc15\\lib"`
- Suggested: `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib`
- Original: `-lopencv_world410`
- Suggested: `lopencv_world410.lib`

Hope it works!

**Edit:** As Scheff mentioned, add the OpenCV DLL files path to the system path variable or add thoese to the application root folder.

Comment: IMHO, if it were a link issue OP should get link errors but not an app crash at program start-up.

Comment: @Scheff OP did not post the error message, so from the configuration of the project file, I found some incorrect configurations, such as double backslashes and so on.

Comment: _But **application is crashing**_ doesn't sound like `qmake` or linker failed. Btw. I suspect that double backslashs in quotes shouldn't be an issue (if not required).

Comment: opencv path was missing in "path" environment variable